# Parsing stored procedures from a file

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
Regex defineProcedureRegex = new Regex(@"\s*(\bcreate\b\s+\bprocedure\b\s+(?:|dbo\.))(\w+)\s+(?:|(.+?))(as\s+(?:.+?)\s+\bgo\b)\s*", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.RightToLeft | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

that I am running against a SQL script file containing multiple "create procedure" statements. The format of the file is like this:

```
use databasename

create procedure dbo.procedure_name
    @param1 varchar(10) -- optional
as

-- do stuff

go


use databasename

create procedure dbo.another_procedure
    @param1 varchar(10) -- optional
as

-- do other stuff

go
```

The problem I have is that I need to match the first `as`, but only the last `go`. Since the procedure body may also contain `as` and `go` (within comments), I can't figure out how to do this reliably.

Any help/comments/advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the procedure body may also contain as and go (within comments)

(and within string literals and identifiers, yes).

You would have to do a greedy match up to `go`. But, that would match from the start of the first stored procedure in the source up to the end of the last one!

You could use a negative match to ensure that the greedy match didn't go over a ‘create procedure’ boundary:

```
(as\s+(?:(?!create\s+procedure).)+?\s+\bgo\b)
```

however this is still not watertight, because you might also have `create procedure` in a comment or string literal.

Conclusion: regex is an inadequate tool for parsing a complex, non-regular language such as SQL. You will need a proper SQL parser. This is not a simple job. See eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net).

Comment: The link is dead, is it possible to update the answer with some other example of parser. Thank you.

Comment: Bah SO! Answers in the now-deleted question included sqlparser.com (not free), stealing a parser from SharpHSQL and for T-SQL specifically using [ScriptDom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779737/using-the-tsqlparser).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create procedure (?<schema>.*?)\.(?<name>\w+)(?<params>[\s\S]*?)?as[\s\S]*?go
```

Note I'm using a non-greedy pattern, i.e. `*?`